# I do not understand where the URL for ASP restful API is set

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I have recently started to learn C# and ASP. I have just created an ASP project using this command:

```
dotnet new webapi -n ProjectName
```

It has has the default sample project. I can build it and run it, and call it from the browser using this URL:

```
http://localhost:5068/WeatherForecast
```

I do not understand how the ***WeatherForecast*** part of the URL is determined, as I can't find that specific string anywhere.

This is the content of the controller:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace ProjectName.Controllers;

[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class WeatherForecastController : ControllerBase
{
    private static readonly string[] Summaries = new[]
    {
        "Freezing", "Bracing", "Chilly", "Cool", "Mild", "Warm", "Balmy", "Hot", "Sweltering", "Scorching"
    };

    private readonly ILogger<WeatherForecastController> _logger;

    public WeatherForecastController(ILogger<WeatherForecastController> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    [HttpGet(Name = "GetWeatherForecast")]
    public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> Get()
    {
        return Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index => new WeatherForecast
        {
            Date = DateOnly.FromDateTime(DateTime.Now.AddDays(index)),
            TemperatureC = Random.Shared.Next(-20, 55),
            Summary = Summaries[Random.Shared.Next(Summaries.Length)]
        })
        .ToArray();
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code has two pieces.  The server and the client.  The code you posted is the client code.  The server code is a webpage that is listening on your machine for a HTTP connection on Port 5068 which is the URL.  You did not post the server code.  Your client code will make a connection to the URL.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @jdweng, however, I am confused... The code in my question is the controller... How does it act as a client? I am just not sure how I can determine how the restful service must be addressed in the browser URL. The equivalent of "@Path ( "/RestfulServiceName" )" in JEE. So, really, where "WeatherForecast" in "http://localhost:5068/WeatherForecast" URL is determined. I knew I have to use that URL because it was made clear, but how would I have worked it out myself?

Comment: Microsoft tries to make actions simple and hide the complexity so it is never obvious what is really happening.  I understand your confusion.  See following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-components?view=aspnetcore-7.0#view-component-methods

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is right there

```
[Route("[controller]")]
public class WeatherForecastController : ControllerBase
{
}
```

The Route attribute has `[controller]` in it which means as much: use the typename of this class without the word `Controller` as the route.

So if you want a different url, either rename `WeatherForecastController` to `MyApiController` or be explicit in the route attribute:  `[Route("myapi")]`

See also [Token replacement in route templates [controller], [action], [area]](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-7.0#token-replacement-in-route-templates-controller-action-area)